# Linq query for unique i'd collection based on one another column value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I have a collection (data table contain three columns A, B & C WHICH has different values). I need a unique collection based on distinct column 'A' AND VALUE OF 'C' column AS Priority

```
1st priority -  completed
2nd priority - business 
3rd priority - System
```

If found one priority need to ignore remaining two

[Input Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fNDZ.png)

[Required Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r0nO.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> orderBy = new List<String> { "Completed", "Business", "System" };

dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(r => new {A = r["A"], C = r["C"]})
       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => orderBy.indexOf(r["C"]).First()))
       .CopyToDataTable();
```